# Component Definition item

Tags: experience-editor, presentation

What is the core usage of a Component Definition item?

Is it used to store the rendering parameters of the component? Or does it allow the component to be added to a placeholder? Or Both?

Answer (score 3):

Component/Rendering/Sublayout (depending how you call it or which technology you are using WebForms or MVC) definition item is an item in Sitecore content tree which defines a rendering.

It is used for storing following information:

- Name
- Description
- Experience Editor buttons
- Global Caching options (if set here will be applied to all instance of rendering).
- what is the Controller name and Action name that should be used to render rendering (in case you are using MVC)
- What is the path to the view file (if you are using WebForms or xslt)
- Parameters Template - what is the template of rendering paramters. If you open renderings options in Experience Editor you will see those options
- Default datasource location
- Datasource template

As you can see it describe the rendering in general. We can say it describe the type of a rendering (similar analogy to object oriented programming concept of type and instance of types)

> It is used to store the rendering parameters of the component

No. Like I said above it is just a rendering (type) definition. If you add rendering to a page then it will create an instance of this rendering but rendering parameters won't be stored in component definition item but in `__Renderings` or `__Final Renderings` fields of your current page item)

This is how rendering instance is stored in one of those fields:

`<r uid="{B343725A-3A93-446E-A9C8-3A2CBD3DB489}" s:par="Param1=Value1" />`

Notice the `s:par` attribute.

> or it allows the components to be added to a placeholder?

To define whether rendering can be added to a particular placeholder is set in different place. Search for `Placeholder Settings` to learn more.

This video might give you some overview:

*Friday Sitecore Best Practice: How to Properly Use Placeholder Settings*
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDNdVLFTNLc